# Java Positioning Problem of JLabel in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, bluej

I´m creating a TileMap out of JLabels and my Problem is that the last Tile is not placed right.
For some reason the last JLablel is on a wrong position. I think this Image:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KpSb.png]

and the Code explains what my problem is.

Btw. I am using BlueJ (maybe there is a bug in it, that I dont know)

Thanks for help!!!

```
    //create Frame
    this.setSize((size+2)*imageSize+16,(size+2)*imageSize+39);
    this.addKeyListener(this);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
    this.setVisible(true);
    //create MapJLabels
    for(int x = 0;x<size;x++){
        for(int y = 0;y<size;y++){
            mapJLabels[x][y] = new JLabel();
            this.add(mapJLabels[x][y]);
            mapJLabels[x][y].setSize(imageSize,imageSize);
            mapJLabels[x][y].setLocation((x+1)*imageSize,(y+1)*imageSize);
            mapJLabels[x][y].setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The code is attempting to set the size/location of the component. This implies you are using a null layout. Don't. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. You should use the `GridLayout`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information.
2. You create an empty JLabel. By default a JLabel is transparent. I'm not sure now the picture you posted is created from the code you posted. I don't see how the grid is populated with images etc.
3. Swing components are visible by default so there is no need for the setVisible(true)
4. Your code attempts to set the size of the frame. Again, don't. When using layout managers you just `pack()` the frame and the size will be calculated automatically.
5. Your code attempts to leave space between the frame and labels. Don't. If you want extra space you can add an `EmptyBorder` to the panel. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Borders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html)
6. You code is using a KeyListener. Don't. Swing was designed to be used with [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)
7. Components should be added to the frame BEFORE the frame is made visible.

The posted code looks reasonable, but since we can't see where you change the background of the labels or where you add icons to the labels, we don't know what the rest of your logic is doing. The problem could be there.

If you need more help after fixing the above problems then post a proper [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your new problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the tips, but I think that doesn't answer my question. As you can see from the screenshot, my program is working very well, except this one JLabel, that you can see is not at the right position.(And the picture is from my code. Of corse it is not all of the code. For example I set the images later in the code.) So there must be a problem with the `setLocation()` Method. Thank you!!

Comment: @Joshey40, yes it does answer the question, the best we can based on the incomplete information provided. We can't confirm or deny if the code is correct since we can't execute the posted code. The code posted looks like it should work, but you obviously have more code. So the first step is to just display the frame with your empty labels and no images to verify if this code is in fact the problem or if the problem is contained elsewhere in your code. The point of the "MRE", is to simplify the code and isolate where the problem is occurring. Without your "MRE" we can't provide any more help.